# CodeIgniter pagination: repeating create_links() fails

Tags: codeigniter

I have a strange behaviour when I try to display pagination links twice.

```
<nav>
    <?=$this->pagination->create_links() ?>
</nav>              
<nav>
    <?=$this->pagination->create_links() ?>
</nav>
```

The first block works fine while the second always resets to page 1:

[image]

It seems like some state-full property in the Pagination class has been altered by the first `create_links()` call

I'm using `$config['reuse_query_string'] = true` in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue just putting the HTML in a variable, easy..

```
<?$paginator = $this->pagination->create_links() ?>
<nav>
    <?=$paginator?>
</nav>
<nav>
    <?=$paginator?>
</nav>
```